# Can't get value of input type="file"?

Tags: javascript, jquery, file, input

I have a `<input type="file" id="uploadPicture" value="123">`

When I'm using: `alert($("#uploadPicture").val());`

It alerts an empty dialog.

Comment: when are you calling that alert?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded and http://jsfiddle.net/LvsYc/638/ may help you :D

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can read it, but you can't **set** it. `value="123"` will be ignored, so it won't have a value until you click on it and pick a file.

Even then, the value will likely be mangled with something like `c:\fakepath\` to keep the details of the user's filesystem private.

Comment: Right -- browsers treat this differently too, for instance firefox will only show the filename after selecting a file, whereas some may show the full path. There is nothing you can really do with this client side.. what are you trying to accomplish OP?

Answer (score 64):

@BozidarS: [FileAPI](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) is supported quite well nowadays and provides a number of useful options.

```
var file = document.forms['formName']['inputName'].files[0];
//file.name == "photo.png"
//file.type == "image/png"
//file.size == 300821
```

Answer (score 14):

You can get it by using document.getElementById();

```
var fileVal=document.getElementById("some Id");
alert(fileVal.value);
```

will give the value of file,but it gives with fakepath as follows

```
c:\fakepath\filename
```

Answer (score 5):

```
$('input[type=file]').val()
```

That'll get you the file selected.

However, you can't set the value yourself.

Answer (score 4):

You can't set the `value` of a `file` input in the markup, like you did with `value="123"`.

This example shows that it really works:
http://jsfiddle.net/marcosfromero/7bUba/

Answer (score 4):

It's old question but just in case someone bump on this tread...

```
var input = document.getElementById("your_input");
var file = input.value.split("\\");
var fileName = file[file.length-1];
```

No need for regex, jQuery....

Answer (score 4):

array of files

```js
let files = document.getElementById('your_input_id').files
```

first file

```js
let file = document.getElementById('your_input_id').files[0]
```

show image onload

```js
const reader = new FileReader()

let files = document.getElementById('your_input_id').files
reader.onload = async (event) => {
    document.getElementById('preview').setAttribute('src', event.target.result)
}
reader.readAsDataURL(files[0])
```