# Programmatically sending data to iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, form-data

I am currently adding in a backup jquery function to replace FormData for support of i.e 9 and below. However i have come across this post:
[jQuery iframe file upload](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7909161/jquery-iframe-file-upload)

I can see that this is for uploading files which I will need but I have quite a lot of fields in my form. Is there a way to programmatically get all text fields in my form without using formData.

I have had a look at using this but it will get all input fields but no textarea fields and it will include images.

```
$("form").each(function(){
    $(this).filter(':input') //<-- Should return all input elements in that specific form.
});
```

Or is there a better way to do this? I don't really want to touch the formData as this works fine for all other browsers but I have included the code

```
if(document.FormData === "undefined")
```

to detect and use another function instead.

EDIT:

just tried the following:

```
$(".inputfield").each(function(index,element){
form.attr("input:text",$(element).val());
});
```

but it doesn't update the iframe

EDIT:

This is the full code i am using to upload the form (hopefully)

```
if(window.FormData === undefined){
                    // create iframe
                    var iframe = $('<iframe name="postiframe" id="postiframe" style="display: none" />');

                    $("body").append(iframe);

                    var form = $('.myform');
                    form.attr("action", "scripts/addtocart.php");
                    form.attr("method", "post");
                    form.attr("enctype", "multipart/form-data");
                    form.attr("encoding", "multipart/form-data");
                    form.attr("target", "postiframe");
                    $(".inputfield").each(function(index,element){
                        form.attr("input:text",$(element).val());
                    });

                    form.submit();

                    $("#postiframe").load(function () {
                        iframeContents = $("#postiframe")[0].contentWindow.document.body.innerHTML;
                        $("#textarea").html(iframeContents);
                    });
                    alert("complete");
            }
```

EDIT: added form:

```
<form class="myform" onsubmit="return false;" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="price" class="inputfield" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" class="inputfield" id="product" name="product" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" class="inputfield" id="sid" name="sid" value="<?php echo $_GET['sid']; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" class="inputfield" id="hiddenvalue" name="label" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" class="inputfield" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" class="inputfield" id="labelquantity" name="labelquantity" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" class="inputfield" id="userlabel" name="userlabel" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" class="inputfield" id="colourlabel" name="colourlabel" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" class="inputfield" id="foillabel" name="foillabel" value=""/>
```

the majority of the rest of the form is generated depending on options chosen previously so abit hard to post that code

Comment: I don't see what you're doing with an iframe in this code, could explain or add code? And a quick note, not sure if English is your first language, but you say "quiet" a couple of times where you mean "quite". "quiet" means "silence" ;)

Comment: @funkwurm English is my first language, spelling certainly isn't my forte, but thank you for pointing that out it will be updated. I will update the question now and more code.

Comment: @funkwurm i've updated now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually add a class to the fields i want to validate, the same rule could be applied for what you want to do..

```
<input type="text" class="req" name="forename" value="Forename.." />
<textarea name="comments" class="req">Comments..</textarea>
```

and the `jQuery`

```
$(".inputfield").each(function(index,element){
    form.append(element);
    //form.attr("input:text",$(element).val());
});
```

**Example**

HTML

```
<form action="scripts/addtocart.php" target="post_requests" enctype="multipart/form-data" type="post">
<input type="hidden" name="price" class="inputfield" value="<?php echo $price; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" class="inputfield" id="product" name="product" value="<?php echo $_GET['id']; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" class="inputfield" id="sid" name="sid" value="<?php echo $_GET['sid']; ?>"/>
<input type="hidden" class="inputfield" id="hiddenvalue" name="label" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" class="inputfield" id="quantity" name="quantity" value="1"/>
<input type="hidden" class="inputfield" id="labelquantity" name="labelquantity" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" class="inputfield" id="userlabel" name="userlabel" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" class="inputfield" id="colourlabel" name="colourlabel" value=""/>
<input type="hidden" class="inputfield" id="foillabel" name="foillabel" value=""/>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<iframe name="post_requests" style="display:none;"></iframe>

<div id="response">
    Waiting for form to be posted..
</div>
```

Javascript

```
function postResponse(_html)
{
    document.getElementById('response').innerHTML = _html;
}
```

scripts/addcart.php

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var _html = 'The form was posted..';

parent.postResponse(_html);
</script>
```

Comment: as my inputs already have classes would it also work like this: class="req test" then do a foreach on .req

Comment: @LiamSorsby did this work for you? if so, could you please accept the answer - if not, please provide feedback and i will try assist you further

Comment: sorry danny, was having a play with it. Doesn't seem to want to post the data to the iframe so not quiet yet. I've edited my post

Comment: could this be because no name is been specified in the created code? if so any advise on how to generate the name on the input field?

Comment: How are you posting it to the iframe?

Comment: So you know: you can post a form directly to an `iframe`, by pointing the `target=""` of your form to the `name` of your `iframe`

Comment: @LiamSorsby see my updated answer.. i believe you need to append the element rather than just add the attr to the form

Comment: i've used the append and i've changed the iframe to be visable for a bit but unforunately using the append the form doesn't show in the iframe

Comment: Neither of them show in the `iframe` - from what i understand, you're building a form and posting it to the `iframe`, if you want to create the form inside the `iframe` thats a different thing

Comment: I may have confused things here. the form is already built on screen which is to be filled out, i just need a way of sending the data over (with ajax but sending text and files over) which is why i opted for using iframes, i have already got a FormData which works but this version is for I.E 9 and below as the majority of our customers use I.E and will be unable to use this site.

Comment: Ok, in that case in the form that is already built, just add the `target="iframenamehere"` and it'll post into the iframe, which will emulate the AJAX form.. Then have a javascript function (`formComplete(the_html)`) on your page to print the result, the result is sent from the iframe destination as `parent.formComplete(the_html);`

Comment: the js has var form = $('.myform'); which changes the attributes to the target to target="postiframe" wouldn't this do the same thing?

Comment: update, i have to form posting to my iframe even though i had event.preventDefault(); i had in my form onsubmit="return false;"

Comment: I think i understand what you want, let me set up an example for you

Comment: No problem, Danny seen as you have spent so long on this i will accept your answer. But the code i originally had worked it was just the darn return false that was blocking it from running! Thank you for your help

Answer (score 1):

This code: `form.attr("input:text",$(element).val());` is setting/overriding an attribute in the `<form>` tag for each element that has class `inputfield`, so by the time you do `form.submit();` there will effectively be this:

```
<form class="myform" input:text="valueOfLastElementWithClass'inputfield'">
```

Which I doubt is what you're trying to achieve. I'm not sure what you **are** trying to achieve, but you can select every `<input type="text"` and `textarea` and `select` in jquery like so:

```
$('input[type=text],textarea,select').each(function(index, element) {
  // do something;
}
```

Comment: thanks, i will give this a go, however it won't just be text it would be textarea and selects aswell.

Comment: Changed it to also select `textarea`s and `select`s, however I don't see what you want to do with them. Are they not already inside of your `<form>` and `</form>`?

Comment: sorry i'll explain further. The purpose of this is i have my Ajax upload working fine, however it doesn't work in ie 9 or below as i was using FormData, so i need to pass all the form into the iframe to be passed into my php script to avoid having to make changes to my add to cart script.

Comment: Could you post (a part of) your form? You don't need to send the form-elements to the iframe individually. Just `submit()` while the `target` has been set to `postiframe` like the existing script already does. The entire form - files, inputs, texareas and selects - will be sent to the iframe

Comment: the form is huge but yes some of the form is above.

Comment: i had onsubmit="return false" that was stopping the file posting to the iframe!!!