# how to add file data in ajax call without using FormData?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, post

How can i add a file data along with some normal data i.e without form in ajax call?
current i have in my ajax script

```
$("body").on("click", "#next-step", function(event){
                $("#loader").show();
                event.preventDefault();               

                var file = $("#upload_logo")[0].files[0];
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'step-two.php',
                    data:{
                      name : "my name",  
                    },
                    file : {upload_logo : file},
                    contentType: false,
                    processData: false, 
                    success: function(response)
                    {
                        $("#loader").hide();
                        alert(response);

                    }
                })


    });
```

i found out the solution but it's not the way i would like it to work

```
event.preventDefault();
                var fdata = new FormData()


                if($("#upload_logo")[0].files.length>0)
                   fdata.append("upload_logo",$("#upload_logo")[0].files[0])

                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: 'step-two.php',
                    data:{fdata},
```

And it works, but my question is what if i just want to add my file in data how can i do this? instead of using FormData() any alternative?

Comment: What is wrong with using `formData()`? It is the accepted method of file upload. Doing something else is using older technology.

Comment: you are right, i want to know isn't it possible just to add file fields just like we add normal input field in data? because i just cant find it anywhere, just like i did in my first code file : {upload_logo : file}, isn't is possible?

Comment: Yes, For the data inside the file to get transferred as part of POST request, we need to use FormData. You can also mix your data with the file content.  data : { name : 'my name', fileContent : fdata}

Comment: so basically i cant add an image without FormData() i just want clarification?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uploading files using AJAX without FormData (IE9)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27006938/uploading-files-using-ajax-without-formdata-ie9)

Comment: @JayBlanchard: everything is wrong with using formData, because I don't want to include every field and I don't use `<form>` at all.

Comment: [Then you can use an older method.](http://www.peachpit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1766159)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

file upload is not possible through ajax. You can upload file, without refreshing page by using IFrame. you can check further detail [here](http://www.ajaxf1.com/tutorial/ajax-file-upload-tutorial.html#)

> With XHR2, File upload through AJAX is supported. E.g. through
>   [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/Using_FormData_Objects) object, but unfortunately it is not supported by all/old
>   browsers.
>
> FormData support starts from following desktop browsers versions. IE
>   10+, Firefox 4.0+, Chrome 7+, Safari 5+, Opera 12+

For more detail, [see MDN link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XMLHttpRequest/FormData)

Answer (score -6):

```
Use Form data 

var formData = new FormData('form id');
  $.ajax({
 type: 'post',
 async: false,
 cache: false,
 url: '',
 contentType: false,
 processData: false,
 data: formData,
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function (response) {

   }
 });
```

Comment: i dont have any form , i just have input fields and my question is how i can do this without using FormData()?

Comment: But you have a click handler why don't you make a request on that particular click?

Comment: This has nothing to with html form in your web page. Its just another object in javascript to get the file content from input type="file".

Comment: i am doing that and i can do it,, my simple question is how can i add an image uploaded via files to add in data in ajax call without FormData()

Comment: Than the only option left is using iframe check out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909442/how-to-make-asynchronousajax-file-upload-using-iframe)

Comment: Author asked you how NOT to use `formData()`;