# How to display selected image without sending data to server?

Tags: javascript, html, file-io

I am trying to show the client an image which he has selected:

```
<input type="file" onchange="showImage(this)"/>
```

But I can't read the value of the input, as I checked out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903323/cant-get-value-of-input-type-file). Is it possible to display the image?

In `onchange` I can send the form to server and server can send the data back, but is it really necessary? Can't the client display the data without the ping-pong to the server? Is it a security issue?

Comment: If you're submitting a form this way then yes - the ping-pong to the server is unavoidable. You could load the image from the local file system with the HTML5 File API and display it.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You can use [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) web-api object for this, see this snippet:

**the HTML**

```
<input id="src" type="file"/> <!-- input you want to read from (src) -->
<img id="target"/> <!-- image you want to display it (target) -->
```

**the javascript**

```
function showImage(src,target) {
  var fr=new FileReader();
  // when image is loaded, set the src of the image where you want to display it
  fr.onload = function(e) { target.src = this.result; };
  src.addEventListener("change",function() {
    // fill fr with image data    
    fr.readAsDataURL(src.files[0]);
  });
}

var src = document.getElementById("src");
var target = document.getElementById("target");
showImage(src,target);
```

Comment: See the link. It should work in all major browsers and since IE10.

Comment: the `var input=this` in your code does nothing. The `input` variable is never used.

Comment: HTML comments are `<!-- -->` instead of `//`

Answer (score 1):

**HTML**

```
`<input type="file" name="img" id="img">
<img alt="" id="imgPreview" style="max-height: 200px; max-width: 200px;">`
```

**JQuery**

`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#img").change(function (e) {
                //console.log(URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
                 $("#imgPreview").attr("src", URL.createObjectURL(e.target.files[0]));
   });
});
```

`