# Store an image in browser storage using input type 'file' - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I'm trying to store an image in the browser storage when the user selects an image from his/her computer.

```
<div className="add_grp_image_div margin_bottom">
     <img src={img_upload} className="add_grp_image"/>
     <input type="file" className="filetype"/>
     <span className="small_font to_middle">Add group image</span>
</div>
```

As shown in the above code i'm opening the file upload window when someone clicks on this div. I want to show the selected image inside the div i have given above. How can i do it?

[image]

My html part looks like this.

Comment: Is requirement to store uploaded file at `Storage`, or display contents of file within `document`?

Comment: I'm trying to use a image-cropper after as well.. So i think i need to store the image.Or is it possible to use a image cropper without storing the image in brwoser storage?

Comment: You can perform tasks on `File` or `Blob` object without storing file object at `sessionStorage` or `localStorage`.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to store the image for showing it to the user or manipulating it.

To show the image, make use of `FileReader` api.  [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138244/how-to-display-selected-image-without-sending-data-to-server) answer should show you how to display the selected image

To manipulate the image, you need to draw it on a canvas and then perform the selected actions. To draw on the canvas you can follow as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4773966/drawing-an-image-from-a-data-url-to-a-canvas)

But if you wanna to crop it, i suggest you to search for a good javascript image manipulation library. There are n libraries that already does this. It saves time and you can learn much faster without re-inventing the wheel.