# How to display a image selected from input type = file in reactJS

Tags: reactjs, filereader, input-type-file

I'm trying to display a image selected from my computer in my web app. I referred the following question which addresses the question i'm trying to fix.

[How to display selected image without sending data to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138244/how-to-display-selected-image-without-sending-data-to-server)

I have my html part like this

```
 <div className="add_grp_image_div margin_bottom">
      <img src={img_upload} className="add_grp_image"/>
      <input type="file" className="filetype" id="group_image"/>
      <span className="small_font to_middle">Add group image</span>
      <img id="target"/>
 </div>
```

I want to display the selected image in

```
<img id="target"/>
```

How can i do this?

I referred `FileReader` docs as well.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader

Answer (score 144, accepted):

**Hook version**:

```
const [image, setImage] = useState(null)

const onImageChange = (event) => {
 if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
   setImage(URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]));
 }
}

return (
  <div>
    <input type="file" onChange={onImageChange} className="filetype" />
    <img alt="preview image" src={image}/>
  </div>
)
```

**Class version**

```
render() {
   return (
     <div>
       <input type="file" onChange={onImageChange} className="filetype" />
       <img alt="preview image" src={this.state.image}/>
     <div/>
   )
}

onImageChange = (event) => {
 if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
   this.setState({image: URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0])});
 }
}
```

Another solution is to use `FileReader`

```
onImageChange = (event) => {
  if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = (e) => {
      setImage(e.target.result);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
  }
}
```

Working demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/priceless-cerf-my900b

Comment: i get this error.  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of null

Answer (score 7):

Recently I came across needing a similar feature. Here is my implementation using `hooks`.

```
export default function App() {
  const [image, setImage] = React.useState("");
  const imageRef = React.useRef(null);

  function useDisplayImage() {
    const [result, setResult] = React.useState("");

    function uploader(e) {
      const imageFile = e.target.files[0];

      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.addEventListener("load", (e) => {
        setResult(e.target.result);
      });

      reader.readAsDataURL(imageFile);
    }

    return { result, uploader };
  }

  const { result, uploader } = useDisplayImage();

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <input
        type="file"
        onChange={(e) => {
          setImage(e.target.files[0]);
          uploader(e);
        }}
      />
      {result && <img ref={imageRef} src={result} alt="" />}
    </div>
  );
}
```

I created a custom `hook` so that it can be reused anywhere in the app. The `hook` returns the image `src` and the `uploader` `function`.
The image `src` can then be linked to the `<img src={..} />` and then on `input` change you can just pass in the `e` to the `uploader` `function`.

Answer (score 3):

hope it works for you

```
            <form onSubmit={form => submitForm(form)}>
              <input
                accept="image/*"
                onChange={onImageChange}
                className={classes.inputImage}
                id="contained-button-file"
                multiple
                name="image"
                type="file"
              />
              <label htmlFor="contained-button-file">
                <IconButton component="span">
                  <Avatar
                    src={mydata.imagePreview}
                    style={{
                      margin: "10px",
                      width: "200px",
                      height: "200px"
                    }}
                  />
                </IconButton>
              </label>
              <Button
                type="submit"
                variant="outlined"
                className={classes.button}
              >
                Default
              </Button>
            </form>
```

**onImageChange**

```
  const onImageChange = event => {
    if (event.target.files && event.target.files[0]) {
      let reader = new FileReader();
      let file = event.target.files[0];
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        setData({
          ...mydata,
          imagePreview: reader.result,
          file: file
        });
      };
      reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    }
  };
```

**submitForm**

```
  const submitForm = form => {
    form.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("image", mydata.file);
    // for (var pair of formData.entries()) {
    //   console.log(pair[1]);
    // }
    const config = {
      headers: {
        "content-type": "multipart/form-data"
      }
    };
    axios
      .post("api/profile/upload", formData, config)
      .then(response => {
        alert("The file is successfully uploaded");
      })
      .catch(error => {});
  };
```