# How do I upload an image with HTML and have it preview on the site with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, input

I was thinking I could use an `<input type="file">` to actually upload the file, and that I would use `document.write()` to put it on the site. Essentially I'm looking for some sort of temporary (or permanent, whatever) image hosting on a page, where you upload a file and it appears on the page without complex handling, redirects, or any language besides HTML and JS. Any suggestions?

Comment: you don't need to upload it to show it. just use FileReader to get a dataURL, or window.URL and a blob.

Comment: @dandavis AFAIK you don't even need `FileReader`, as what you have is already a `File` object. `File` extends `Blob`, so you can create a dataURL directly from that.

Comment: If you really want to upload a file then you would have to write some server side code. If as Dan and John above have said, you just want to show the selected image on the page, then that's possible in JS alone: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138244/how-to-display-selected-image-without-sending-data-to-server

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```js
function preview(file){
  if (file) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onloadend = function () {
      document.getElementById("img").src = reader.result;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="file" accept="image/*" onchange="preview(this.files[0])"/>
<br\>
<img id="img"/>
```