# The output image does not appear

Tags: javascript, html, forms, output

```html
<form action="">
    
        <h2>Fill out the following details: </h2>
        
        <div class="inp">
            <label for="name">Name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="name">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="inp">
            <label for="rollno">Roll No: </label>
            <input type="text" id="rollno">
        </div>
        <br>
        <div class="inp">
            <label for="image">Image: </label>
            <input type="file" id="image" accept="image/jpeg">
        </div>
        <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">

</form>

<div id="output">
    
        <h2>Your Details: </h2>
        
        <div class="out">Name: <span id="outname"></span></div>
        <div class="out">Roll No: <span id="outrollno"></span></div>
        <div class="out">Image: <img id="outimage" width="200px"></div>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    
        function displayImage()
        {
            var x = document.getElementById("outimage");
            var y = document.getElementById("image").src;
            x.setAttribute("src",y);
        }
        
        document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function()
        {
            document.getElementById("output").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("outname").innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value;
            document.getElementById("outrollno").innerHTML = document.getElementById("rollno").value;
            displayImage();
        }

</script>
```

Can someone tell me why is this happening? The image is in the same folder as the HTML file. Is there a better way to achieve this? I want to display the image that is selected in the form by the user.

[image: This is the output that I'm getting]

Comment: May you fix the syntax errors in your example?

Comment: you need to read the file and then set the source in preview image src.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display selected image without sending data to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17138244/how-to-display-selected-image-without-sending-data-to-server)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure that you read the content of the image file which is being uploaded. use `filereader` and then `readAsDataURL` and once the content is loaded by `filereader` assign that as `source` to preview image placeholder.

```js
function readURL() {
  // just to avoid the error since i dont know what readURL is doing nor it is mentioned in the OP.
}

function displayImage() {
  var x = document.getElementById("outimage");
  var file = document.getElementById('image').files[0]
  var fr = new FileReader()
  fr.readAsDataURL(file)
  fr.onload = function(e) {
    x.setAttribute("src", this.result);
  }

}

document.getElementById("submit").onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("output").style.display = "block";
  document.getElementById("outname").innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value;
  document.getElementById("outrollno").innerHTML = document.getElementById("rollno").value;
  displayImage();
}
```

```html
<form action="">

  <h2>Fill out the following details: </h2>

  <div class="inp">
    <label for="name">Name: </label>
    <input type="text" id="name">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="inp">
    <label for="rollno">Roll No: </label>
    <input type="text" id="rollno">
  </div>
  <br>
  <div class="inp">
    <label for="image">Image: </label>
    <input type="file" id="image" accept="image/jpeg" onchange="readURL(this)">
  </div>
  <button type="button" id="submit">Submit
</button>
</form>

<div id="output">

  <h2>Your Details: </h2>

  <div class="out">Name: <span id="outname"></span></div>
  <div class="out">Roll No: <span id="outrollno"></span></div>
  <div class="out">Image: <img id="outimage" width="200px"></div>
</div>
```