# Reading the name of a File with Javascript/jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Currently I am making a program in which works as a text editor. I have a section where you can rename the title, and when you save, it takes that `document.getElementById('title').innerHTML` and makes it the `.txt` name.

For example:

If the title div had the innerHTML of "Document", the file would be called "Document.txt".

My problem is that I want it to also upload a file and take its file name.

For example:

I uploaded a file called "Document.txt", and the function makes the title "Document". (I am using a `.replace('.txt','')` to make it not show in the title and a `+= '.txt'` to make the file actually a .txt when saved.

Anyone know how to make the file name of the uploaded document using an `<input type='file'>` a string to be used elsewhere?

Here is some code to put it in perspective:

```
var id = function(id){return document.getElementById(id)};

function readText(that)
    {
        var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = function(e)
            {  
                var output = e.target.result,
                    name = FILENAMEFIND();
                id('page').innerHTML = output;
                id('title').innerHTML = name;
            }
        reader.readAsText(that.files[0]);
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cant get value of input type="file"?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903323/cant-get-value-of-input-type-file)

Comment: yes, you are correct, however it contains the ``C:\fakepath\`` which I don't want, any clue how to remove that? I guess just ``id('upfile').replace('C:\fakepath\','')`` would work, but will the file always be in C drive? any idea how to do that?

Comment: Not clear what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: answer below...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out myself:

```
var id = function(id){return document.getElementById(id)},
    input = id("upfile"),
    file = input.value.split("\\"),
    fileName = file[file.length-1];   // Take purely the file name
    id('title').innerHTML = fileName; // Outputted to title div
```