# get element by ID: how to select a file a manipulate it later

Tags: javascript

I was wondering how can I get the value from the selected file. I am using

```
document.getElementById("file1").click()
```

so is it fine to use like this :

```
var v = document.getElementById("file1").click();
```

Comment: [HTMLElement.click()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/click) doesn't return anything. So your `v` will be `undefined`. Are you looking for something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/29176118/1647737

Comment: If you are trying to get the value of a file input(???)
[Can't get value of input type=“file”?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903323/cant-get-value-of-input-type-file)

Comment: @ThomasWikman thanks but how can i get the output file? i am trying to get an image so i can manipulate it with thresholding

Comment: All i can do is direct you to a resource with lots of examples of what you can achieve with JavasScript and "Files". I hope you find it usefull.
https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Time for me to say godnight.

Comment: @ThomasWikman thanks alot and have good day